# Error while form opening if it is created from SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath, content-type

I got stuck! :P

My goal: New form in source library ====> New form in target library [both web-browser enabled, following Infopath templates]

- Using "create list item" action within a workflow (which runs when an item is created in the original library) step in SharePoint Designer.
- It works as supposed and creates the form in the target library.
- However, these forms can't be opened from the web browser. (Depending the case, it could throw an error like the following one: "This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath.").

Just to clarify what I've already done and (re)checked:

- I've set "Open forms in web browser" as default option in the target library.
- When creating forms using the option "add new document", they are perfectly added to the library (and accesible/editable through the web browser itself).

Does anyone have any clue about this issue? I've been searching a long time in Google without any luck ( there's a similar -unaswered- question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-BZ/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/905b4140-5bd3-4371-8aa0-f4ef9d4d7360 ).

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:**

I've just found out that the SPD is creating a .xsn file instead of the .xml created when "adding a new document" (manually).

This gave me more ammo to "google" the issue, and found that this is a kind of weird behavior of SharePoint ... and several workarounds ( 1) http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/06/create-infopath-forms-sharepoint-designer-workflow/ and 2) social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/903d70e9-0fd0-4092-b4e2-cb3a0cd7baa9 )

Isn't there a cleaner way to achieve this? Is this problem solved in SP 2013? Any hint would be really appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using SharePoint Online (2013) to try to do something similar. The workflow locks up when trying to create the new Infopath form in the library the error message includes a GUID with lots of 0s. The new item was not created in the library.

Doing the workaround of definining the template as an xml file allowed the new file to be created in the SharePoint  library, but the icon wasn't an InfoPath icon, it was a plain xml icon, and when trying to open it, I see a blank form (without the IP customisations).

So it looks like it is still a problem.